# How do I remove an element from a hashtable using its value and not the key?

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm new to hash table and I'm just figuring out the basic operations on it.
I have a hash table created as shown below and inserted values also.

```
Hashtable<Integer , String> ht = new Hashtable<Integer , String>();
ht.put(1234, "ABCD");
ht.put(2345, "EFGH");
ht.put(4567, "IJKL");
```

I am able to delete the element needed using the key as shown below

```
System.out.println("Deleting entry with key 2345");
ht.remove(2345);
System.out.println(ht.toString());
```

which gives the following output

```
Deleting entry with key 2345
{4567=IJKL, 1234=ABCD}
```

I am not able to find any method which helps with locating the element in the hashtable using the value as an index and deleting the element. How do I go about it?

Comment: Do you care about how efficient this operation is? If you do, you need a different data structure.

Comment: Uh, you _are_ aware that a value can appear multiple times in a map, right?

Comment: @NPE How do I improve on it?

Comment: @fge Yes. I do get that. But like i said, I'm new to using hash tables. Just figuring out heads and tails of it now by using simple operations.

Comment: Well, the purpose of a `Map` is to access entries by key, not value. Some libraries (Guava for instance) do have bidirectional maps, but removing a key given a value is not a `Map`'s "simple operation" ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
ht.values().remove("ABCD");
```

this will remove one entry with the specified value, if there may be multiple entries with the same value you can use this

```
ht.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton("ABCD"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Navigate using [Map.entrySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) and check for [Map.Entry#getValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) equality.
You can have a value multiple times so iterate entrySet using an `Iterator` and delete elements using `Iterator.remove()`

```
void deleteItem(String item) {
  Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = it.next();
    if(entry.getValue().equals(item)) {
      it.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Integer, String> map = ...

Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = it.next();

  // Remove entry if value equals xxx.
  if (entry.getValue() != null && entry.getValue().equals("X")) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```